# Selecting rows using inner join

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `SalesTbl` and `CreditDepositsTbl`.

- `SalesTbl` has columns SalesNo, ItemDesc, SalesID
- `CreditDepositsTbl` has columns ID, ItemDesc, SalesID
- `SalesTbl` has 2 rows with `SalesID = 26112019/0004` and
- `CreditDepositsTbl` has 2 rows with `SalesID = 26112019/0004`

The challenge is, I want to get `SalesNo, ItemDesc` and `SalesID` from `SalesTbl` and `ID` from `CreditDepositsTbl`.

I used the inner join keyword in my query:

```
select  
    sa.SalesNo, sa.ItemDesc, sa.SalesID, cd.ID
from 
    SalesTbl sa 
inner join
    CreditDepositsTbl cd on cd.SalesID = sa.SalesID
where 
    sa.SalesID = '26112019/0004'
```

The query returns 6 rows instead of 2. Please what I'm I doing wrong.

Comment: Show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: If you are getting 6 rows instead of 2, it means that both one of those tables has more SalesID with '26112019/0004'.

Comment: that's what happens with a many to many relationship.

Comment: How do you have two rows in the SalesTBL with the same SalesID? That seems to indicate that column isn't the primary key even though the name sounds like it should be. If you have two rows in each table all with the same SalesID how could you know which row in the second table belongs to which row in the first table?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DISTINCT? Such as:

```
  select  DISTINCT
sa.SalesNo, sa.ItemDesc, sa.SalesID, cd.ID
```

from

```
SalesTbl sa 
inner join
CreditDepositsTbl cd on cd.SalesID = sa.SalesID
where sa.SalesID = '26112019/0004'
```

Also, take a look at [this](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join)

It explains one to many using JOIN and should give you a clear path to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think the issue is that the OP has multiple rows in CreditDepositsTBL and they want only one row for each row in SalesTBL. I don't think distinct will work here, they probably need an aggregate to get the total of deposits. But hard to say as there isn't a lot of detail yet.

Comment: I agree. SQL isn't exactly my wheelhouse and I have encountered this in the past. I posted a link in my edit. Hopefully that will help the OP..

Comment: @hounddog75 I tried select distinct, it doesn't work.

Comment: @sean lange    I want all the columns from the SalesTbl and only the ID column from the CreditDepositsTbl.

Comment: Did you take a look at the link I included in my post about one to many and using JOIN? It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to some kind of aggregation to get this to work.

```
select SalesID, TotSales,TotCCpmts
from (
      Select SalesID,SUM(SalesAmount) TotSales
      from SalesTbl
      group by SalesID ) sa     
join 
    (
     select SalesID,SUM(CreditcardPayment) TotCCpmts
     from CreditDepositsTbl 
     group by SalesID) cd on cd.SalesID = sa.SalesID
where sa.SalesID = '26112019/0004'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's expected in a one-2-many relationship.

So aggregate 'em

```
SELECT sa.SalesNo, sa.ItemDesc, sa.SalesID
, COUNT(cd.ID) AS TotalCreditDeposits
, MIN(cd.ID) AS MinimumCreditDepositId
, MAX(cd.ID) AS MaximumCreditDepositId
FROM SalesTbl sa 
JOIN CreditDepositsTbl cd 
  ON cd.SalesID = sa.SalesID
WHERE sa.SalesID = '26112019/0004'
GROUP BY sa.SalesNo, sa.ItemDesc, sa.SalesID
ORDER BY sa.SalesNo, sa.ItemDesc, sa.SalesID
```

But something feels off about this.

Normally when an ID field is named after it's table (F.e. `SalesTbl.SalesID`) the it's often the primary key of that table.
And a primary key can't have duplicates.
But yet you claim there are 2 SalesTbl.SalesID equal to '26112019/0004'?

So it this a bad Many-To-Many relation without foreign keys?

Comment: The PK for SalesTbl is SalesNo and the PK for CreditDepositsTbl is ID. The SalesID is only used to classify a Group of sales.

Comment: Confusing naming then.  And if there's no `CreditDepositsTbl.SalesNo` then there's no One-2-Many relationship.  And I doubt that the `ItemDesc` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, the reason why I wanted to get the SalesNo is to be able to update both tables with the  SalesNo in each table. But I found a way to insert the SalesNo into CreditDepositsTbl directly using

```
insert into CreditDeposits (CreditorID, DepositAmt, ItemDesc, ItemID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Amount,
TransDate, TransTime, SalesID, UserID, StockNo, ServerDate, ServerTime, Discount, 
TransType, Returned, ReturnedQty, SalesNo, CreditorRep)
select CreditorID, 0, ItemDesc, ItemID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Amount,
SalesDate, SalesTime, SalesID, UserID, StockNo, SalesDate, SalesTime, 0, 
'CREDIT', Returned, ReturnedQty, SalesNo, @CreditorRep from Sales where sales.SalesID=@SalesID
```

So there's no need getting the SalesNo from the Sales table. I'm able to update both Sales and CreditDepositsTbl with SalesNo.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your tables on a column whose value is not unique. So there is a cross join mode.
Certainly in one of the tables SalesID = 26112019/0004 there are three times in the other table and 3 * 2 = 6.